# Send Data via AJAX and print result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

EDIT - On my web dev it says the request was cancelled so I added return false on the onsubmit. Now nothing happens

I am trying to send some data via ajax to my PHP and it doesn't seem to work. Here is the Javascript which does the AJAX request:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("searchBox");
search.onsubmit = function() {
 return false;
 $.ajax({
    url: 'request.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {text_box: textBox.value},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
 });
};
```

and then here is the PHP that deals with the request:

```
echo $_POST['text_box'];
```

Comment: Can you please show how you define the `textBox` variable

Comment: Edited to add textBox variable @Spokey

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why you don't use the JQuery post method insted?

```
var textBox = $('#searchBox').val();
$.post( "request.php", { text_box: textBox}, function(data) {
   alert(data);
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/full/path/to/request.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {text_box: searchBox.value},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that my code was already like that, is it because my javascript file is in a different folder to the php file? @Olim-Saidov

Comment: If requesting php file is in a different folder you should specify correct `url` in ajax call i.e. `url: '/full/path/to/request.php'`

Comment: Ok so the js file is in a different folder but the html file is in the same folder as the html file. Does the request come from the html file or the js file?

Comment: It comes from html file. Can you please post Firefox/WebDev tool screenshot.

Comment: URLs are resolved relative to the HTML file that executes the code, not the JS file that contains the code.

Comment: It says that the request has been cancelled and it is red

Answer (score 0):

You haven't encoded your data or provided a key name for it.

```
data: { text_box: searchBox.value },
```